# Image upload functionality for drupal 7 content

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I am using CKEdtor and i want image uploading functionality in drupal 7. What is the solution for that ?

Comment: Are you just using the CKEditor module or are you using the WYSIWYG module utilizing the CKEditor library?

Answer (score 3):

Install the [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce) file browser module.  This will let you integrate direct file uploading while editing content, which of course includes images as well.  Follow the directions on the module's homepage for linking it with CKEditor.

Comment: when using the wysiwyg module there is also a imce<>wysiwyg bridge module - this works like a charm

Comment: Does that work if he's just using the CKEditor module without the WYSIWYG module?

Comment: i don't know what exactly is used ;)